# How to display default value of textbox then append input after button click

Tags: html

Good day! seeking help again for my html project, below is the script and button command that I used. I want the input boxes to have a default value of Model, IMEI and Serial by default when no input is detected upon button click. Now when I input values to the boxes, I want the input to appear after the default values after a colon (e.g. Model: SM-G900I) Is it possible or not? THanks again for the help :) Here is a link for the output that I want to achieve by the way http://picpaste.com/test_fields-DicIgF8B.JPG

```
<script>
function showInput2(){
var ui1 = document.getElementById('model').value;
var ui2 = document.getElementById('imei').value;
var ui3 = document.getElementById('serial').value;
document.getElementById('display2').innerHTML = ui1 + '\n' + ui2 + '\n' + 
i3;
}
</script>

<p><label>Model</label>
<input type = "text" id = "model"  /></p>

<p><label>IMEI</label>
<input type = "text" id = "imei" /></p>

<p><label>S/N</label>
<input type = "text" id = "serial"  /></p>

<button type="submit" onclick="showInput2();">Submit</button><br/>
<p><textarea name="device details" cols="33" rows="5" id='display2'>
</textarea></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before submitting the form compare whether user entered something else other than the default value.

```js
function showInput2(){
var ui1 = document.getElementById('model').value;
var ui2 = document.getElementById('imei').value;
var ui3 = document.getElementById('serial').value;
//checking of empty string for model
if(ui1.trim() != '')
  ui1 = 'Model: ' + ui1;
//Checking for empty string for IMEI
if(ui2.trim() != '')
  ui2 = 'IMEI: ' + ui2;
//Checking for empty string for Serial
if(ui3.trim() != '')
  ui3 = 'Serial: ' + ui3;
document.getElementById('display2').innerHTML = ui1 + '\n' + ui2 + '\n' + ui3;
}
```

```html
<p><label>Model</label>
<input type = "text" id = "model" /></p>

<p><label>IMEI</label>
<input type = "text" id = "imei" /></p>

<p><label>S/N</label>
<input type = "text" id = "serial" /></p>

<button type="submit" onclick="showInput2();">Submit</button><br/>
<p><textarea name="device details" cols="33" rows="5" id='display2'>
</textarea></p>
```

Comment: how can I make the default values invisible and only make them appear on button click?

Comment: Thank you very much @ Hassan Imam, this made my life more easier :)

Comment: You are welcome @neilsensolis. I am glad I could be help to you :)

Answer (score 0):

Just add a value attribute in your text type .

```
<p><label>Model</label>
<input type = "text" id = "model" value="test value"/></p>
```

Same for others text type .

Answer (score 0):

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("input").val("");
    $("input").on('change', function(event){
    id = event.target.id;
    var value = id + ":" + event.target.value;
    $('#' + id).val(value);
    });
})
```

Add this to your javascript .. this will get the id of the input clicked and append the new value to the id follwed by colon and newwly enetered value.

change your html to

```
<p><label>Model</label>
<input type = "text" id = "Model"  value="Model"/></p>

<p><label>IMEI</label>
<input type = "text" id = "IMEI" value="IMEI"/></p>

<p><label>S/N</label>
<input type = "text" id = "Serial"  value = "Serial"/></p>
```

Comment: the output does not show the colon between the default value and input value. and also how can I make the default value invisible on the input box?

Comment: @neilsensolis modified my code to default values invisible initially .. the output will show the default value only after you come out of the field since we bid the event to change

Comment: please see picture on link since that is what I am referring to. I know its a bit unclear on what I am trying to accomplish so I hope the picture will help give you an idea

http://picpaste.com/test_fields-DicIgF8B.JPG